# How to generate Code Review report from Github

Tags: github, report, pull-request

For auditing purpose, we need to generate a code review report from our source code repository. Earlier we used to generate this from TFS, but since we migrated to GitHub recently, we wanted to understand how this is done for GitHub. Is there any off the shelf or home-grown tool available for this. I assume in GitHub it would be a PR details report rather than code review report.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported natively by GitHub itself.

You have various [Code Review GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/category/code-review) (meaning pipelines executed some linters on GitHub server side), but that is not the same as the [TFS Core Review Report](https://docs.devart.com/review-assistant/analyzing-code-review-performance-with-reports/reports-overview.html).